# php bin/console symfony commands give a fatal error

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I installed a symfony 3 project but cant run any php bin/console commands. When I try, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement? in project_folder/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Any idea how to see the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can we see the file that refers to "DOMDocument". Just "edit" your post, and post that code.

Comment: I installed symfony with 'symfony new project_name' and then entered the folder and tried 'php bin/console to see if the console was working.  After hours of looking for solutions I checked the php packages that I had installed and realized that php-xml was not there.  Now it is working. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After hours of looking for solutions I checked the php packages that I had installed and realized that php-xml was not there.

```
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Now it works :)

Comment: Works. But I hate these php programs and their unreasonable error message

Comment: Personally I had to run `sudo apt install php7.0-xml`